# Where to place the location code in a tabbed application?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-location

I happen to have a three-tabbed application where each tab is a fragment. In one of the fragments, I need to get the user's location and in an activity other than the main, I also need to grab the user's location.

My question is this: Where is the best place to place the code to grab the user's location?

I have cut and pasted the same code into both locations (fragment and activity), but that seems extremely inefficient. I would think that I would place the code in the Main activity and use static values... any suggestions/comments would be appreciated.

Also, would "best practices" dictate that if I'm using a tabbed interface that I keep to only one activity and use fragments for everything such as actionbar functions?

Thanks,

min = 18
target = 19

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating another class and put your codes in it (static methods) and call them from both the activity and the fragment. **Note**: it doesn't differ from putting your code in both classes. Something like:

```
public class LocationUtil {

    public static boolean isGpsEnabled(Context context) {
        // Relative code
    }

    public static boolean isNetworkEnabled(Context context) {
        // Relative code
    }

    public static Location getCurrentLocation(Context context) {
        // Relative Code
    }

}
```

But if you **don't** need to get user's current location every time you open the app (I didn't need, at first I asked him to choose a location) I recommend getting the location only once and storing it in `SharedPreferences`, because it uses less battery and power.

Again if you want to get the location on a regular interval, I suggest using `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`. You can check how here.

I don't get your last question completely, but it doesn't differ a lot.

**A Friendly Suggestion:**
If you don't need things which are introduced at API 18, decrease your `minSdkVersion`, because a lot of devices (such as my phone) will miss your app.

**Hope it helps :)**